# Highlight the different parts of a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, nicematrix

I want to highlight the different parts of a matrix. I have used this code, but it can not work well. How can I modify it?

I want to build the following figure:

[image]

I have using the nicematrix in the following, but this is the output **using Overleaf**:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\overlay}[2][]{\tikz[overlay,
  remember picture, #1]{#2}}
\tikzset{
  highlighted/.style = { draw, thick, rectangle,
                         rounded corners, inner sep = 0pt,
                         fill = red!15, fill opacity = 0.5
                       }
}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \overlay{
    \node [fit = (left.north west) (right.south east),
           highlighted] (#1) {}; }
}
\newcommand{\flag}[2]{\overlay[baseline=(#1.base)]
  {\node (#1) {$#2$};}}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \begin{pmatrix}
    \flag{left}{p_1}, & p_2, & \flag{right}{p_3}, & \cdots, & \flag{left}{p_1},& p_2-p_1,& \flag{right}{p_3-p_2},&\cdots \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \highlight{N}
  \qquad
  M^T = \begin{pmatrix}
    \flag{left}{p_1} & p_2 & p_3  \\
    p_1, & p_2-p_1, & \flag{right}{p_3-p_2}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \highlight{NT}
\]
\overlay{
  \draw[->, thick, red, dotted] (before) -- (after);
  \draw[->, thick, red, dashed] (N) -- (NT)
    node [pos=0.68, above] {};
  \node[above of = N ] { $x$   };
  \node[above of = NT] { $z$ };
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using `tikz` but you are nowhere using `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: I've used this link and I have tried to modified it https://latex-cookbook.net/highlight-formula/

Comment: Another thing is how you set the matrix. You don't separate an element from each other using commas followed by ampersand. You only use ampersand. Edit: Did you mean to represent this as column vector?

Comment: Yes. I want a column vector.

Comment: Pleas see the update with arrows.

Comment: Thanks, @simondispa. I don't know why, but in my overleaf, the number is not shown. I have added the figure to the question.

Comment: From the manual "We create a rectangular Tikz node which encompasses the nodes of the 
rows with the Tikz library fit. This Tikz node is filled after the construction of the matrix. In order to
see the text under this node, we have to use transparency with the blend mode equal to multiply.

**Caution** : Some pdf readers are not able to show transparency. In Overleaf, the “built-in” pdf viewer does not show transparency. You should  switch to your own “native” viewer."

Comment: Download the pdf from Overleaf and use your own pdf viewer.

Comment: See also the answer of F. Pantigny, on the last version of `nicematrix`, to avoid using transparency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I applied the `nicematrix` package to replicate the manual drawing. It uses Tikz nodes, so the syntax will be familiar to you.

[image: y]

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<
 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}        

\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle,
        fill=red!15,
        blend mode = multiply,
        rounded corners = 0.5 mm,
        inner sep=1pt,
        fit = #1}}          
    
\[
M = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, extra-margin=2pt]
        & x     &       &           &       &y          &           & \\
    p_1,& p_2,  & p_3,  & \cdots    & p_1,  & p_2-p_1,  & p_3-p_2,  &\cdots \\
\CodeAfter \tikz \node [highlight = (1-1) (1-3)] {} ;
\tikz \node [highlight = (1-5) (1-7)] {} ;      
\end{bNiceMatrix}\] 

\bigskip

\[
M^T = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,extra-margin=2pt]
            &z          &       \\
    p_1,    & p_2,      & p_3  \\
    p_1,    & p_2-p_1,  & p_3-p_2
        \CodeAfter \tikz \node [highlight = (2-1) (2-3)] {} ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** (with arrows)

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<
 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

% from https://latex-cookbook.net/highlight-formula/
\newcommand{\overlay}[2][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture, #1]{#2}}

\newcommand{\flag}[2]{\overlay[baseline=(#1.base)]
{\node (#1) {$#2$};}}   

\begin{document}        

\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle,
        fill=red!15,
        blend mode = multiply,
        rounded corners = 0.5 mm,
        inner sep=1pt,
        fit = #1}}          
    
\[
M = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, extra-margin=2pt]
        & x                 &       &           &       &y          &                       & \\
    p_1,& p_2, \flag{Mx}{}  & p_3,  & \cdots    & p_1,  & p_2-p_1,  & \flag{My}{}p_3-p_2,   &\cdots \\
\CodeAfter \tikz \node [highlight = (1-1) (1-3)] {} ;
\tikz \node [highlight = (1-5) (1-7)] {} ;      
\end{bNiceMatrix}\]


\bigskip

\[
M^T = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,extra-margin=2pt]
            &\flag{MTz}{z}          &       \\
    p_1,    & p_2,      & p_3  \\
    p_1,    & p_2-p_1,  & p_3-p_2
        \CodeAfter \tikz \node [highlight = (2-1) (2-3)] {} ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

    \overlay{
    \draw[->, thick, red, dotted] (Mx) -- (MTz);
    \draw[->, thick, red, dotted] (My) -- (MTz);
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nicely done. I used `nicematrix` for this and it positioned the elements very well. Normal matrix environments seem to displace the elements out of parenthesis. Now I recommend giving a semicolon after the first `cdots` in matrix M to actually make it a column vector. Plus remove commas in the matrix `M^T` and `cdots` at the end of each row to make a valid transpose.

Comment: He did also draw the arrows in the example. You might want to draw that here as well.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Remark: With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.16 of 2021-06-20), it's possible to obtain the same output without the use of transparency (due in your code to `blend mode = multiply`).

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification of Simon Dispa's answer which does not use transparency   thanks to the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.16 of 2021-06-20).

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<
 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}        

\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle,
        fill=red!15,
        rounded corners = 0.5 mm,
        inner sep=1pt,
        fit = #1}}          
    
\[
M = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, extra-margin=2pt]
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \tikz \node [highlight = (1-1) (1-3)] {} ;
  \tikz \node [highlight = (1-5) (1-7)] {} ;      
\Body
        & x     &       &           &       &y          &           & \\
    p_1,& p_2,  & p_3,  & \cdots    & p_1,  & p_2-p_1,  & p_3-p_2,  &\cdots \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}\] 

\bigskip

\[
M^T = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,extra-margin=2pt]
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \tikz \node [highlight = (2-1) (2-3)] {} ;
\Body
            &z          &       \\
    p_1,    & p_2,      & p_3  \\
    p_1,    & p_2-p_1,  & p_3-p_2
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]